# Unicity condition for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous function on a neighborhood of $y_0$. If the differential equation:
$$y'=f(y)$$
Has two solutions that pass through the point $(0,y_0)$, prove $f(y_0) = 0$
$$$$I have tried using the condition for unicity for equations of the form:
$$F(x,y,y')=0$$
In which the non-unicity implies:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(0,y_0,f(y_0))=0$$
But $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=1$. Am I applying something wrong?

Comment: @AlexR. you need $y(0)=y_0$ but the second solution you provided doesn't fit. Moreover, the first one neither, since in that case you would have $f(y)=y'=(y_0)'=0$

Comment: @AlexR. What the hell, hahah my bad :p

Comment: @OussamaBoussif: No, my bad. $y_0=0$ is implied by what I wrote earlier.

Comment: @AlexR. Ah yes, you're right, didn't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(y_0) \neq 0$, then there is only one local solution satisfying $y(0) = y_0$.

Namely, if $J$ is an open neighborhood of $y_0$ where $f\neq 0$, then the function
$$
F(y) := \int_{y_0}^y \frac{1}{f(s)}\, ds, \qquad y \in J
$$
is locally invertible, being a bijection from $J$ to $F(J)$.

Hence the unique local solution of the Cauchy problem is given by
$$
y(t) = F^{-1}(t),
$$
for $t$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: This is perfect. If $f(y_0) \ne 0$ we have a separable equation, for which unicity is easily verified.